# I am sometimes getting out of memory while training a model

Tags: tensorflow, out-of-memory, artificial-intelligence

Tensorflow Version : TF1.13
Using Anaconda

I studied in stack overflow to set :
TF_CUDNN_WORKSPACE_LIMIT_IN_MB = 100
To reduce the scratch space for tensorflow which is 4GB by default

GPU : NVIDIA GTX 1660 TI 6GB card
CUDA Version : 11.0

But I do not know how to set the environment variable.
I couldn't find any tutorial on it. Since I am a beginner with this can anyone give any links or tell how to set this variable?? It would be really helpful for me.

Comment: note thatv 100mb is way lesss than the default 4gb, so are you sure you want to set this limit, maybe it wont be enough

Comment: Thanks a lot for replying so fast. The point is I dont know how to set that variable. I would rather set that variable to even 1 gb but my major concern is how should i set the variable value that is what is the method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `OS` module in python as follows:

```py
import os

os.environ['TF_CUDNN_WORKSPACE_LIMIT_IN_MB'] = '100'
```

And by the way, 100MiB is way much less for a model to be trained. At least allocate it 1GiB.

Comment: Sorry I use stack overflow but this is the first time that I posted a question. Sorry once again and thanks a lot for the help!!! I really appreciate it.